# The size of the UIActivityIndicatorView by different version of software

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

When I test my app on iphone, I find that the size of the spinner(UIActivityIndicatorView) is displayed differently on different version of iphone software.

The default style is "UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite", the size is appropriate on 5.1 but really really small when on 4.2.1. So I think I have to set the size by :

```
[spinner.layer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f] forKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
```

According to different version. The problem I want to ask is should I treat or the version below 5.0 as the condition as on 4.2.1 that I have tested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is completely up to you. If you want to support your application for iOS 4.2 and higher, use the arithmetic for 4.2 else go for 5.0.